# Difficulty Importing a txt file into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to import a txt file (into a DataFrame) that looks like this

```
12345           20191113418824004           S20191013
23456           20191030T20.60XA            X20191230
```

The  data frame must look like

```
memberid    Date1      Code        Flag   Date2
12345       20191113   418824004   S      20191013
23456       20191030   T20.60XA    X      20191230
```

So far I tried doing

```
data = pd.read_csv ("diag.txt",delimiter = "\t")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['memberid','Date1','Code','Flag','Date2'])
```

but I am getting all the columns as NAN. Not sure why even the memberid column is not picking up.
Any guidance is much appreciated.

Here are the Rules for seperation-

1. Lets take the first row: `12345           20191113418824004           S20191013`. The first continuous series of numbers (until we hit the first space) `12345` are the `memberid`
2. In the next blob / chunk of numbers we encounter (`20191113418824004`) the first `8` numbers of this become the `Date1`. Whatever is left after the first `8` numbers becomes the `Code` (In this case `20191113` becomes the date and the rest `-418824004` is the code )
3. In the next chunk of data we encounter `S20191013` . The first letter becomes the `Flag` and the rest becomes the `Date2`. This third "column" if I may say is always `varchar(9)`. So in this case S is the flag and the rest  `20191013`  is `Date2`.

P.S This is all random mock data that I manually generated. No sensitive information.

Comment: I don't know if there's a copy and paste issue with the `txt` file but are the values actually stuck together like that in the file or are there tabs present between `S20191013` for example? And if the values are actually stuck together like that, can you outline the rules for how they should be separated into columns?

Comment: Hello, Its not a copy paste issue. I have updated my question with the rules for how they should be seperated. I'd higly obiliged if you could take a look. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("your_file.txt", sep=r"\s+", header=None)
df[["Date1", "Code"]] = df.pop(1).str.extract(r"(\d{8})(.*)", expand=True)
df[["Flag", "Date2"]] = df.pop(2).str.extract(r"([A-Z])(.*)", expand=True)
df = df.rename(columns={0: "memberid"})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   memberid     Date1       Code Flag     Date2
0     12345  20191113  418824004    S  20191013
1     23456  20191030   T20.60XA    X  20191230
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed-wide data, you may want to use [pandas.read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas.read_fwf) instead of read_csv so that you don't have to parse that afterwards but directly have the proper specification when reading, which would look the following (widths is a list with each of the column widths, not a cumulated sum of them, be careful with those):

```
In [1]: pd.read_fwf("test.txt", widths=[16, 8, 20, 1, 30], header=None)
Out[1]:
       0         1          2  3         4
0  12345  20191113  418824004  S  20191013
1  23456  20191030   T20.60XA  X  20191230
```

If you want to have the column names, you may pass them as names parameter:

```
In [34]: pd.read_fwf("test.txt", widths=[16, 8, 20, 1, 30], header=None, names=['memberid','Date1','Code','Flag','Date2'])
Out[34]:
   memberid     Date1       Code Flag     Date2
0     12345  20191113  418824004    S  20191013
1     23456  20191030   T20.60XA    X  20191230
```